# Jboss AS 7 logging on wrong level

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss7.x

I have been trying to use my own log4j.xml file for logging, as suggested here:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F

I did the following things:
- I created the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in WEB-INF (since my application is a WAR file) with the corresponding content;
- I put log4j-1.2.16.jar in my build path;
- created log4j.xml in src/main/resources (this is where Spring Roo put the file when it generated the project).

This way, my logging messages from my classes are displayed ok, but errors that bubble up and are caught by DispatcherServlet are shown at DEBUG level in the Console:

```
12:06:30,668 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-localhost-
127.0.0.1-8080-3) Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved
error   view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'uncaughtException'; model is
{exception=java.lang.NullPointerException}: java.lang.NullPointerException at
ro.radcom.muzee.bo.impl.JmsServiceImpl.sendMessage(JmsServiceImpl.java:29) [classes:] at
ro.radcom.muzee.web.HomeController.redirectGet(HomeController.java:56) [classes:] at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33] at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33] ....
```

In standalone.xml, the logging part looks like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <logger category="com.arjuna">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="sun.rmi">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="jacorb">
        <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="jacorb.config">
        <level name="ERROR"/>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

Also, although my log4j.xml contains this:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.security">
     <level value="info" />
</logger>
```

in the console there are some DEBUG level logs such as:

```
"12:06:30,659 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor]"
```

1. What could be the causes?
2. Are these 2 problems related in some way?

   Any help would be appreciated .

   Thank you.

**
   Application server: JBoss AS 7
   IDE: Springsource Tools Suite

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It looks like Spring is logging debug messages and you have the console and root logger set to level debug.

Comment: Yes, I set the root logger level to debug to register all logs for DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR. That's how it works, right? Well, the first log sample is an ERROR but it is shown as a DEBUG, and the last log sample is a DEBUG, although I specifically set INFO level for org.springframework.security. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

From the logging subsystem perspective it looks like everything is working as it should. Spring is printing `DEBUG` messages and you have the root logger set to print them as well as the console handler.

Your example messages look like they are using the format from the logging subsystem. I'm not sure if you have a format defined in your `log4j.xml` configuration file, but my guess is that you're configuration file is not be found or used.

The key things to using your own log4j configuration are;

- Make sure you're excluding the servers log4j library (looks like you are with the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`
- Make sure you include a log4j library within your deployment
- Make sure the log4j configuration file is visible to log4j in your deployment